# Parameter index out of range despite having made sure I did everything else right

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Ok, I want to preface. I have searched through multiple people having this issue and none of that seems to be my problem.

```
 String Statement = "INSERT INTO DAISYEMPLOYEE"
                    + "(SSN, FNAME, MINIT, LNAME, ADDRESS, DATEHIRED, PAY, PHONE#) VALUES "
                    + "( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, Statement, "Daisy Imports", 3);

            try {
                PreparedStatement PST = connection.prepareStatement(Statement);
                PST.setInt(1, 11);
                PST.setString(2, "NAME");
                PST.setString(3, "a");
                PST.setString(4, "asdasd");
                PST.setString(5, "123 hobo street");
                PST.setString(6, "2017-05-06 ");
                PST.setString(7, "8.5");
                PST.setString(8, "1231231234");

                PST.execute();


            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "PUERILE CAPTION REMOVED", "Daisy Imports", 3);
                Logger.getLogger(Game.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } // try
```

I totally have parameters, I have no idea whats happening.

Comment: Not sure what database you are using, but using `PHONE#` as a column name sounds suspect. Try avoiding the `#`.

Comment: I have a connection set up elsewhere in the program. Deleting the # and changing the name in the database fixed it. wow >.> I feel like an idiot